# Android Need event Foreground and Backgorund

Tags: android, application-lifecycle

Hi Friends i am making an application in which i need to show something when user goes in background and again when user comes in foreground. So i Need to get an event when our app goes in background and again when app comes in foreground working in api above 8.

I tried all thing but only able to recognize if my app is foreground or not. I need event when we come again online at application level.

Comment: this [link](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html) helps in working around my issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can define a superclass for all your activities and track the state of the app. If all activities are in stopped state - app in the background, otherwise - in the foreground. In `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods of your super activity you can increment and decrement the number of visible activites. Then in `onStart()` and `onStop()` check if there was any currently visible activity. If no - app becomes active/inactive and you can call your method:

```
public class SuperActivity extends Activity {
    private static int sVisibleActivitiesCount;

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        if (SuperActivity.sVisibleActivitiesCount == 0) {
            onAppBecomesActive();
        }
        SuperActivity.sVisibleActivitiesCount++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStart();
        SuperActivity.sVisibleActivitiesCount--;
        if (SuperActivity.sVisibleActivitiesCount == 0) {
            onAppBecomesInactive();
        }
    }

    private void onAppBecomesActive() {
        // Do some staff
    }

    private void onAppBecomesInactive() {
        // Do some staff
    }
}
```

The second approach is to use [ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html) (min API 14) for monitoring activities lifecycle and track application state in a single place without having a super class for all activities. So I would rather use this approach if your app has minSdkVersion="14".

Comment: could also add a boolean in a custom implementation of Application  and edit it in onStart onStop via getApplication() and casting.  So don't need the counting.

Comment: thanx for your response But i need event only when App becomes foreground and background. But your approach is marvellous @makovkastar